# SingleChildScrollView does not work inside column

Tags: flutter

I need to put a SingleChildScrollView in a column. When I do so, the SingleChildScrollView does not work.

I have a page that has a bunch of vertically laid out Widgets. The first three are intended to be static. The rest of the widget are dynamic in number, and should scroll.

Based on the requirements I have used a column, with a SingleChildScrollView as the on of the children. When I do so, the scroll view does not scroll.

This seems like a common case that should be handle, right?

Comment: show some code!

Comment: @MoaidALRazhy You dont know what a SingleChildScrollView in a Column looks like?

Comment: I know dear but it helps to add on modify easily and make the sentence "  does not work. " understood thats why :)

Answer (score 1):

first way give the scrollview parent container with specified height

second way wrap the scrollview with expanded

Comment: if that solved your question mark question as answered